# Ошибки Docker Compose "unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f" и "unknown flag: --file"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Команда:

```
docker compose -f postgres.yml up -d
```

Ошибка:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
```

C такой командой все работает:

```
docker-compose -f postgres.yml up -d
```

Команда:

```
docker compose --file postgres.yml up -d
```

Ошибка:

```
unknown flag: --file
```

C такой командой все работает:

```
docker-compose --file postgres.yml up -d
```

- Моя ос: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
- Docker и Docker-Compose устанавливал с официального сайта:
- Docker version 24.0.7
- Docker Compose version v2.23.3